# shortcuts involving the "ctrl" button stopped working while in edit mode

Tags: shortcut

**environment :**

windows 10 home edition
blender 3.01

What i did:

1.Entered enter
edit mode

2.Selected edge mode

3:Pressed ctrl+r

**Result**

Nothing happened

**Notes**

-All existing loops were not brocken
so it should have worked

- I also tried that with other shortcuts
  such as ctrl+m
  or ctrl +i

result was the same

only happens with shortcuts that uses ctrl+(enter letter here)

**tried to fix by:**

- uninstalling and reinstalling
- reload factory settings.

none of those worked.

how do i fix this?

Comment: did you confirm the ctrl key works in other programs?